# How to pass useFrom methods to child component using typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hook-form

```
const methods = useForm<Module>({
  defaultValues: defaultValues,
  mode: "onChange",
  shouldFocusError: true,
  shouldUnregister: true,
  resolver: yupResolver(module)    });
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xMNF9.png) which props do I need to use indeed of UseFormProps.

How to pass this methods props to the child component using typescript

Comment: Please include relevant code as text, not screenshot

Answer (score 1):

In order to pass the methods to a child component inside a form you need to use `useFormContext` see documentation here:   [react hook form doc](https://react-hook-form.com/api/useformcontext)

```js
import React from "react";
import { useForm, FormProvider, useFormContext } from "react-hook-form";

export default function App() {
  const methods = useForm();
  const onSubmit = data => console.log(data);

  return (
    <FormProvider {...methods} > // pass all methods into the context
      <form onSubmit={methods.handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
        <NestedInput />
        <input type="submit" />
      </form>
    </FormProvider>
  );
}

function NestedInput() {
  const { register } = useFormContext(); // retrieve all hook methods
  return <input {...register("test")} />;
}
```